# Different unique rows

Tags: matlab, row

I have a function which finds the ROWS in an array having repeating number and replaces them by the a unique row.
Here is the function:

NVAR= number of parameter in the unique row

PVBu= upper bound of the numbers in the row

lower bound is 1 by default

```
function [A]=nonrepeatuniquerow(A,NVAR,PVBu)
HM = zeros(1,NVAR);
p = zeros(1,PVBu);
 for j = 1
 p(1:PVBu) = 1:PVBu;
 for k = PVBu:-1:PVBu-NVAR+1
 q = ceil(k*rand);
 HM(j,PVBu-k+1) = p(q);
 p(q:k-1) = p(q+1:k);
 end
 end
b = any(~diff(sort(A,2),1,2),2) | any(A==0,2);

A(b,:) = repmat(HM,sum(b),1);
end
```

For example,

Assume [9 1 7] is the unique randomly generated row.

Matrix A is passed to the function 'nonrepeatuniquerow'.

```
A= [2 3 3
    2 5 2
    1 5 9
    9 7 6]
```

And output is:

```
A= [9 1 7
    9 1 7
    1 5 9
    9 7 6]
```

My question is how to modify the function so that it replaces the ROWS having a repeating number by DIFFERENT unique rows ?

For example the output could be as follows:

```
A= [7 2 3
    2 1 8
    1 5 9
    9 7 6]
```

The function below only generates unique rows every time it is called.

NVAR=number of parameter in the unique row

PVBu= upper bound of the numbers in the row

lower bound is 1 by default

```
function [HM]=generateunique(NVAR,PVBu)

HM = zeros(1,NVAR);
p = zeros(1,PVBu);
 for j = 1
 p(1:PVBu) = 1:PVBu;
 for k = PVBu:-1:PVBu-NVAR+1
 q = ceil(k*rand);
 HM(j,PVBu-k+1) = p(q);
 p(q:k-1) = p(q+1:k);
 end
 end
end
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `nonrepeatuniquerow`, the first part is just for creating the random sequence `HM`. You could run through all non-unique rows in a for loop and create a separate `HM` for each. That would look like this:

```
function [A]=nonrepeatuniquerow(A,NVAR,PVBu)

b = any(~diff(sort(A,2),1,2),2) | any(A==0,2);
for ii=find(b==1).'
    HM = zeros(1,NVAR);
    p = zeros(1,PVBu);
    for j = 1
        p(1:PVBu) = 1:PVBu;
        for k = PVBu:-1:PVBu-NVAR+1
            q = ceil(k*rand);
            HM(j,PVBu-k+1) = p(q);
            p(q:k-1) = p(q+1:k);
        end
    end
    A(ii,:) = HM;
end
end
```

You could also replace the `generateunique` function or the part which does the same in your code by the built-in `randperm` function. You can create a unique random sequence by

```
HM = randperm(PVBu,NVAR);
```

that would give you the following code

```
function A = nonrepeatuniquerow(A,NVAR,PVBu)

b = any(~diff(sort(A,2),1,2),2) | any(A==0,2);
for ii=find(b==1).'
    A(ii,:) = randperm(PVBu,NVAR);
end

end
```

Comment: Ah okay i understood! Thank you very much your kind response @hbaderts. It's very nice of you to take the time to answer my question so fully. The codes works great! I really appreciate your help.